# Static noise from amplifier and it increases when i touch guitar strings

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers

https://streamable.com/76kpb1

I made a video of the issue i am facing, it's my first electric guitar so idk what's the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s a grounding issue. Try a different cable. Or it could be inside the guitar. I just had that issue with a bass player yesterday at work. 1/4” cable was bad.

Comment: Where did the cable get plugged into the *bass player*..?

Comment: @Tim you don’t wanna know

Comment: I've felt like doing that to some of the bass players I've worked with..!

Comment: @Timinycricket I ordered a new cable yesterday and tested it out today, the issue is resolved. It works perfect now. Thanks for your help.